# Iterate through custom ListView to save checked checkboxes and spinners

Tags: android, checkbox, spinner

I have Activity A that runs Activity B with a button click.

Activity B has a list view with custom rows:

some rows have a title and checkboxes.

and some rows have a title and a spinner .

each row the user either checks the preferred checkboxes or chooses from a spinner.

so far so good. my problem is , when clicking back to Activity A, how do I save all the choices? 
and by save I don't mean just save his checked boxes but also get the values of his choices back to Activity A.

I don't want the choices to be saved even after I restart the app. only when the app is running .

So basically I need to  : 
1. get the user's choices and save their values (either from a spinner or from the checkbox)
2. save the ticked checkboxes the next time the user clicks to go to activity B

I thought about using onPause in Activity B , where I will get a reference to the listView, go through every row, see if there is a checkbox or a spinner there, and then somehow see what value is checked (if its checkboxes) and what value is selected(if its a spinner).

I don't know if it's the right approach or not, anyway I really need help here.

Comment: Is your ListView poulated from an array of Objects? If so I would update the state of each object in the list when an option is chosen and then pass the whole list to Activity B.

Comment: my list is populated from A:  LinkedHashMap<String,List<String>> and B: List<String> which in A the key is the title and the list is the choices to use in either a checkbox or a spinner. B is a list that has values either "checkbox" or "spinner" so that when I populate the list I will know which kind of view to inflate